# SSRS 2008 doesn't render report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I have several computers that can render a large report with no issues, however, several other computers cannot render the report and crash reporting services.

We have SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 and we have observed that the reporting services application's memory usage increases from 300MB to 1,2GB when this report is being rendered.

Here we have the log file when this report crashes:

```
rshost!rshost!4cf0!06/26/2013-10:33:38:: e ERROR: WriteCallback(): failed to write in write callback.
rshost!rshost!4cf0!06/26/2013-10:33:38:: e ERROR: Failed with win32 error 0x03E3, pipeline=0x00000000063D2400.
rshost!rshost!106c!06/26/2013-10:33:38:: e ERROR: HttpPipelineCallback::SendResponse(): failed async writing response.
rshost!rshost!106c!06/26/2013-10:33:38:: e ERROR: Failed with win32 error 0x03E3, pipeline=0x00000000063D2400.
httpruntime!ReportServer_0-1!106c!06/26/2013-10:33:38:: e ERROR: Failed in BaseWorkerRequest::SendHttpResponse(bool), exception=System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800703E3): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703E3)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.HostingInterfaces.IRsHttpPipeline.SendResponse(Void* response, Boolean finalWrite, Boolean closeConn)
   at ReportingServicesHttpRuntime.BaseWorkerRequest.SendHttpResponse(Boolean finalFlush)
library!ReportServer_0-1!106c!06/26/2013-10:33:38:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeInternalException: RsWorkerRequest::FlushResponse., Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeInternalException: An internal or system error occurred in the HTTP Runtime object for application domain ReportServer_MSSQLSERVER_0-1-130167083080132500.  ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800703E3): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703E3)
   at ReportingServicesHttpRuntime.BaseWorkerRequest.SendHttpResponse(Boolean finalFlush)
   at ReportingServicesHttpRuntime.RsWorkerRequest.FlushResponse(Boolean finalFlush)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
```

Any idea of what could produce this error? Why this apperars in some computers and everything OK in other?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Server Reporting Services (the online interface) and the problem appears for the end users (reading only your report) and the most important you are sure that the report is working properly.

You might try to cache the report first. That might solve your problem and also make the end user more happy since the report will be loading extremely fast.

You can read about caching here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/caching-reports-ssrs

and here some old instruction how to set up the caching:
http://bhushan.extreme-advice.com/caching-ssrs-reports/

BTW you should also make sure that:
-users have the same rights as you
-the files are up to date and available for all of the users

It is hard to say from here what could be the issue. Try your luck with cache if it won't help to fix this problem... It will definitely bring your reporting and happines of you clients to the new level.

Cheers,
Kacper